# How to train the FCN model on pretrained VGG16

Tags: python, tensorflow, pre-trained-model, semantic-segmentation

I am new to semantic segmentation, I implemented the FCN network and now I want to try not to train from scratch and use the pre-train vgg16 weights. I saw an implementation like this [link](https://github.com/JunshengFu/semantic_segmentation/blob/master/main.py#L83), but I am not sure where the new dataset input comes to the network. 
To be more clear, in the above link, the vvg part returns input image from trained network and the the output layers 3,4,7.

```
 image_input, pool3_out, pool4_out, fc7_out = self._load_vgg16()
```

I am not sure where the new batch of data gets into the model. I appreciate your guidance.